# How can you 'mail merge' on Facebook?

Tags: email, facebook

I have an event on Facebook that a number of people are attending. I'd like to send a message to each of the attendees, and I'd like the message to start with 'Hi !'.

This is similar to the old concept of mail merge where you have a list of recipients whose data you fill in to a template message before sending it to them.

Any ideas on how I could go about doing this? Any 3rd-party tools that you can use to script Facebook?

Comment: facebook mail's pretty simplified - I don't think there's any way to get around this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot be done natively through Facebook.

Your only hope is to be able to export your Facebook contacts and run them through a mail merge on your local.

Or try and upload/import the contacts list to Gmail and use Google Docs as a way to send out personalised mass emails.

If you wanted to try your hand at the Gmail & Google Docs method, ["Create a Mail Merge with Gmail and Google Docs"](http://www.labnol.org/software/mail-merge-with-gmail/13289/) has some steps. They are roughly thus:

1. Create a new Google Docs Spreadsheet
2. Select "Mail Merge" from the menu and allow authorisation access to Gmail and/or Google Contacts
3. Create a new group on Google Contacts with the emails and details of those you want to send to
4. Click **Mail Merge → Import Google Contacts** and select the name of the new group. The details should import.
5. Compose the email as desired
6. Go to the Mail Merge menu and click **Start Mail Merge**. The sending will begin and update.

There's a little more nuance in the link mentioned, but listed here is the general step direction you'll be taking.